# Fresco. How to get image size without loading full bitmap

Tags: android, fresco

I have some local images with unknown size. Format is jpeg. 
The task is resize it to fit max size 1280x960 *keeping original aspect ratio* and save it to new file with low memory consumption. I found out very useful method in Fresco lib: `JpegTranscoder.transcodeJpeg()` operating streams. It has `scaleNumerator` param that rules downsampling. How can I get original bitmap size with Fresco without full bitmap loading to memory to calculate `scaleNumerator` value? Something like [inJustDecodeBounds](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html#inJustDecodeBounds) in android BitmapFactory.Options class

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to use Fresco's [`BitmapUtil.decodeDimensions(...)`](https://github.com/facebook/fresco/blob/df2854a76786f58e044a71617309cc3c0a0c358c/imagepipeline-base/src/main/java/com/facebook/imageutils/BitmapUtil.java#L91) for this.